# HttpContextBase.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice is set to False for Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, .net

I'm trying to detect whether a device should be served the mobile version of my site, however, with the Samsung Galaxy S4, the IsMobileDevice check is returning false. This is the only phone that is failing to be detected as a mobile phone. Has anybody had a similar issue, or know of any work around?

Comment: Not sure if you're still concerned about fixing this issue, but I had the same issue regarding the newer phones. If you 51degrees added to your project, download the newest browser declarations from 51degrees.codeplex.com/releases/view/109691 Add the file to your app_data and finally set the binaryfilepath in webconfig to point to the file in app_data. Hope this helps